# How can I locate an element using selenium 2 which do not have unique identifiers like Name, Id

Tags: java, html, css, selenium-webdriver

Initiate Auto Precall (Shipper) 
 Initiate Auto Precall (Consignee) 
 Log Manual Precall (Shipper) 
 Log Manual Precall (Consignee)

Comment: Have you tried xpath?

Comment: <li 
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Initiate Auto Precall (Shipper)</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Initiate Auto Precall (Consignee)</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Log Manual Precall (Shipper)</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Log Manual Precall (Consignee)</a>
</li>

Comment: @Igor I did try the xpath but all the elements have the same xpath: .//*[@id='ui-active-menuitem']

Comment: Which element do you want to reach? Can you clarify a bit the question? Format the html?

Comment: @Paolof76  my first comment has the actual html, please copy and paste the comment HTML here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_output and see the output, am trying to select "Initiate Auto Precall (Consignee)" option I tried the xpath but they all have the same identifier  ...Thank you for requesting clarity

Comment: Are you sure the html code is that? It is malformed, it starts with <li and then again with an <li>...

Comment: @Paolof76 ,Yes that is the correct HTML code that am using to inspect the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As per your given code in comments, Found solutions for finding element which had listed by you.**

**Solution 1 :**

**Use List of element and get it.**

```
 List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.className("ui-corner-all"));
```

Now get element by index.

For Initiate Auto Precall (Shipper)  `allOptions.get(0);`

For Initiate Auto Precall (Consignee)  `allOptions.get(1);`

For Log Manual Precall (Shipper)     `allOptions.get(2);`

For Log Manual Precall (Consignee)    `allOptions.get(3);`

**Solution 2 :**

**Use xpath as under given :**

For Initiate Auto Precall (Shipper)  `(//a[@class='ui-corner-all'])[1]`

For Initiate Auto Precall (Consignee)  `(//a[@class='ui-corner-all'])[2]`

For Log Manual Precall (Shipper)     `(//a[@class='ui-corner-all'])[3]`

For Log Manual Precall (Consignee)    `(//a[@class='ui-corner-all'])[4]`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath>"));
```

**Solution 3 :**

**Use text() and contains() functions in xpath.**

For Initiate Auto Precall (Shipper)

`//a[contains(text(),'Initiate') and contains(text(),'Shipper')]`

For Initiate Auto Precall (Consignee)

`//a[contains(text(),'Initiate') and contains(text(),'Consignee')]`

For Log Manual Precall (Shipper)

`//a[contains(text(),'Log') and contains(text(),'Shipper')]`

For Log Manual Precall (Consignee)

`//a[contains(text(),'Log') and contains(text(),'Consignee')]`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath>"));
```

Hope you found solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you would like to retrieve web element by its text content.
Due to css does not allow you do text based search, xpath is the only option for you. Try this:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[a[text() = 'Initiate Auto Precall (Consignee)']]"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but that gave me an error of element not visible within 30s. I tried increasing the implicit wait time to 60s but kept getting the same error of element not visible. ........  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.02 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("<CSSSelectorHere>")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...xpath seems have solved the issue.